# App crashes on Back button when SCNCamera is rotating

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, scenekit, scncamera

Did not found question or answer so posting it myself. My app crashes when I have `Allow camera control` enabled for my SCNView, then swipe so camera starts rotating and then press Back button in navigation bar. Crash stacktrace:

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x18)
    frame #0: 0x0000000113e3d94b libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 11
    frame #1: 0x00000001158a2eb6 SceneKit`__42-[SCNCameraController _setInertiaRunning:]_block_invoke.166 + 31
    frame #2: 0x00000001173e33f7 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    frame #3: 0x00000001173e443c libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 8
    frame #4: 0x00000001173ef6f0 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 628
    frame #5: 0x00000001149bbee9 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    frame #6: 0x0000000114980592 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 2402
    frame #7: 0x000000011497f9b9 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
    frame #8: 0x00000001199a29c6 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 62
    frame #9: 0x000000011029b5e8 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 159
  * frame #10: 0x000000010e6f73e7 ShowIt`main at AppDelegate.swift:13
    frame #11: 0x0000000117460d81 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
    frame #12: 0x0000000117460d81 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

So message send to deallocated camera and app crashes.

Comment: Not sure what `pointOfView` in your view is. But seems it can be fixed by make it `weak` reference. I guess this from your own answer.

Comment: I didn't set anything into `pointOfView`

Comment: Seems like the reason is the view has strong reference. Try making it weak.

Comment: I can't `SCNView` is an Apple class and `pointOfView` declared in `SCNSceneRenderer` as follow: `public var pointOfView: SCNNode? { get set }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this solution:

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

    if isMovingFromParentViewController {
        // Prevent crash on back tap when camera rotates
        scnView.pointOfView = nil
    }
}
```

Basically just set camera node to `nil` when controller pops.